# timeout command does not exit even after process run to completion

Tags: linux, bash, shell, timeout

I am using timeout on a prolog script as follows:

```
timeout 10s swipl -s test.pl "testarg" || printf "timed out!\n"
```

The above command works as expected when typed in the terminal, and prints `timed out!` only when a script runs for a long time.
But when the above line is placed in a script file and executed, it shows a weird behavior where a fast prolog script finishes running (prints expected outputs) but the timeout command still waits for 10s, and prints out `timed out!` at the end.
I am running this in a remote terminal and bash version is `4.2.37`.
What could be causing this difference in behavior? What are some workarounds?
PS: Running from a script works correctly in my personal computer running Ubuntu.

Comment: Btw.: I suggest to use: `printf "%s\n" 'timed out!'`

Comment: I assume that your fast prolog script did not terminate the swipl process after running? What happens when you run just run `swipl -s test.pl "testarg"; printf "Done!\n"` from a script file? What happens when you run `ps aux|grep swipl` after the script finished running and before `timed out!` is printed?

Comment: If I run without timeout in a script, it terminates immediately and print "Done!". The `ps` output between script end and timeout shows the running swipl process: `T    01:07   0:00 swipl -s test.pl testarg`